# Count repeated element in a csv file

Tags: python, csv, collections, count

this is my csv file :

```
2017-07-14  03:05:23    B2KPRT320   - Error1
2017-07-14  03:05:23    B2KPRT320   - Error1
2017-07-15  03:05:23    B2KPRT320   - Error2
2017-07-15  03:05:23    B2KPRT320   - Error3
```

and I need to count the errors per day

this is my script so far :

```
import collections
Data = []
string = ""
array = []
with open('out.csv') as f:
    for line in f:
        Data.append([word for word in line.strip().split("\t")])

for item in Data:
    try:
        date,error = item[0],item[3]
        string = date + "\t" + error + "\n"
        array.append([word for word in string.strip().split("\t")])
    except IndexError:
        print "A line in the file doesn't have enough entries."
```

at the end , I need to save the result in another csv file
this the output :

```
2017-07-14   - Error1   2
2017-07-15   - Error2   1
2017-07-15   - Error3   1
```

Comment: What do you need help with?

Comment: I would look at `collections.counter`. Feed it your list of (date, error) tuples and let it count for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can read the file into a list and use `collections.Counter()` to count the duplicate errors, and then `split()` each line to get 1st and last item. For example:

```
import collections
Data = []
string = ""
array = []
with open('test.txt') as f:
    Data = collections.Counter(f.read().splitlines())

for item, c in Data.items():
    item = item.split()
    date, error = item[0], item[-1]
    string = "{}\t{}\t{}".format(date, error, c)
    array.append(string)


for elem in array:
    print elem
```

This will output:

```
2017-07-15  Error3  1
2017-07-15  Error2  1
2017-07-14  Error1  2
```

**EDIT:**

You don't need to `try/except` anymore because using `item[-1]` gives you last item of the list. Instead you can use:

```
if len(item) < x:
    # print error
else:
    # the above code
```